# MySQL: query throwing column does not exist error

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer.customer_ID, customer.`Name`, customer.Home_Phone, 
customer.Work_Phone, inventory.`condition`, inventory.equip_name
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental_agreement R ON customer.customer_ID = R.customer_ID
INNER JOIN rental_detail E ON E.agreement_num = R.agreement_number
INNER JOIN inventory I ON E.Item_number = I.item_Number
WHERE E.real_return IS NOT NULL;
```

It works as intended when I remove the two inventory columns from the select section, but when I add them back in it tells me these two columns don't exist.

P.S. Also the query might not actually work since the database is currently empty so if you see some glaring problem I'd appreciate it, I'm a tad new to SQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aliased the table, use the alias in the select instead of the table name (ie, once aliased, `inventory` does not exist, but `I` does)

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer.customer_ID, 
                customer.`Name`,
                customer.Home_Phone, 
                customer.Work_Phone, 
                I.`condition`, 
                I.equip_name
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental_agreement R ON customer.customer_ID = R.customer_ID
INNER JOIN rental_detail E ON E.agreement_num = R.agreement_number
INNER JOIN inventory I ON E.Item_number = I.item_Number
WHERE E.real_return IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Nice spot. I am for consistency - use aliases all the time or none of the time - to avoid these types of issues.